# Can we mix non polar and polar molecules by providing heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, polarity

Polar molecules don't dissolve with non polar molecules because of difference in forces of attraction between them. But if we provide enough heat will they mix?

Comment: It is not like do not nor do, but rather do little or do more.

Comment: Entropy of mixing increases with temperature (TΔS term increases), so at elevated temperatures, mixing can become possible.

Comment: This really should use proper jargon. *Substances* dissolve, not molecules. Everything can "mix", but issue is what would in achieve: colloid, true solution, suspension? If the question is supposed mean "Does solubility rise with temperature" then it better say it...

Comment: Can you run faster than a man? Well, the answer is exactly that: it depends. The men are different, and so (or more so) are the molecules.

Comment: Sure Simply vaporize both and they will mix as a gas. Polar water vapor mixes well with nonpolar N2 and O2.  In the condensed phases mixing and dissolution are complicated ask anyone in the cosmetics business how to make the perfect lipstick or hand cream, or even ice cream for that matter, here cold is important.

Comment: Your assumption (at least substituting "substances" for "molecules") is wrong. There is no binary distinction between polar and non-polar substances or their relative solubility. Non-polar hydrocarbons happily dissolve in ethanol (which is fairly polar) but not in water. But water happily dissolves in ethanol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. When cooking my cranberry-orange jam I boil sugar solution containing the cranberries and some cut oranges, and the [hydrocarbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonene) that gives the orange peel its flavor mixes in. Yum!